# Unable to resolve the selecting and deselecting of the checkboxes

Tags: vb.net, vba

Basically Im a vba programmer and Iam facing a serious problem with the checkbox controls of the VBA.I have to select and deselect the checkboxes as per user selection. I believe this is a general question for vb.net also.

some sample code

```
 sub chk3_Click()

  if userform.chk3.value = true then
     userform.chk4.value = true
     userform.chk2.value = true
  end if

 end sub

 sub chk4_click()

  if userform.chk4.value = true then
     userform.chk3.value=true
     userform.chk1.value=true 
  end if

 end sub
```

This is the sample code, I have to turn on the other checkboxes based on user selection of the checkboxes.but the problem Im facing is when it executes the statement

```
userform.chk4.value = true in the sub chk3_click
```

it is invoking the sub chk4_click sub  and again finding the

```
userform.chk3.value=true in sub chk4_click(), invoking the sub chk3_click
```

I am unable to understand how to solve it .

I have tried with various events mousedown, mouseup and  change in value also after update but none worked.These events are crashing the tool I dont understand why but they are crashing so I just ignored to use those events.

Finally I have used a flag which is defined globally in the workbook and using the if condition I have did it but its looking to bad style of coding. Could anyone help me with these ?

This is what I have done to resolve the problem . It works but I dont think its good style of programming.

```
 dim i as integer

sub ch3_click()

  if i = 0 then
     i = 1
     if userform.chk3.value=true then
        userform.chk4.value =true
        userform.chk2.value=true
     end if
     i = 0
  end if

end sub

sub chk4_click

  if i = 0 then
     i = 1
   if userform.chk4.value = true then
      userform.chk3.value=true
      userform.chk1.value=true
   end if
     i = 0
  end if

end sub
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is actually a very valid way to approach the problem, you just need to have a more descriptive name and type for i, such as

```
Dim InClickEvent As Boolean
```

Then change your click event code to something like:

```
  if Not InClickEvent then
     InClickEvent = True
     if userform.chk3.value=true then
        userform.chk4.value =true
        userform.chk2.value=true
     end if
     InClickEvent = False
  end if
```

Even better is if your version of VBA supports Try/Finally, which I believe it does, you can make sure the flag is always cleared even if you have errors with the following version of the code:

```
  if Not InClickEvent then
     Try
        InClickEvent = True
        if userform.chk3.value=true then
           userform.chk4.value =true
           userform.chk2.value=true
        end if
     Finally
        InClickEvent = False
     End Try
  end if
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Application.EnableEvents

```
 sub chk3_Click()
  Application.EnableEvents =false
  if userform.chk3.value = true then
     userform.chk4.value = true
     userform.chk2.value = true
  end if
  Application.EnableEvents =true
 end sub

 sub chk4_click()
  Application.EnableEvents =false
  if userform.chk4.value = true then
     userform.chk3.value=true
     userform.chk1.value=true 
  end if
  Application.EnableEvents =true
 end sub
```